# заменить числа в строке из десятичной в двоичную систему счисления

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача с сайта Информатикс №2805 https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?chapterid=2805#1.

Необходимо все числа в строке из десятичной в двоичную систему перевести, я вроде сделал всё правильно, но сверив, обнаружил что не совпадают.

код:

```
string = input()
some   = string.replace("0", bin(0)[2:])

for i in range(1, 10):
    ready = bin(i)
    some = some.replace(str(i), ready[2:])

print(some)
```

На входе получаю строку - 6^&678JKjdkdl;?.,lk879Pk1kdfl4839,

На выходе - 110^&1101111000JKjdkdl;?.,lk10001111001Pk1kdfl1001000111001

А должно быть - 110^&1010100110JKjdkdl;?.,lk1101101111Pk1kdfl1001011100111

**Подскажите пожалуйста в чём может быть ошибка.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ошибка конкретно в принципе кода, он переводит в двоичную систему не числа, а цифры.
например 1101111000: 110 - 6;  111 -7; 1000 - 8.

Comment: ааа, вот оно что, ну тупанул я, благодарю, сейчас попробую иначе